# Jsonp Angular2 Error CallBack

Tags: angular, angular-http

In my Angular2 App i call API EndPoint with a service

```js
this.jsonp.request(middlewareUrl, { method: 'Get' })
            .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
      console.log("post data");

  }
```

and recive this response :

```html
Response_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."headers: Headersok: truestatus: 200statusText: "Ok"type: 3url: "http://localhost:4000/matches?callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished"__proto__: Bodyconstructor: Response(responseOptions)toString: ()__proto__: Object
```

the endPoint return this:

_todayMatchesCallback({"matchlist":["match1","match2",ecc]}).

can we have any idea or solution for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the returned callback does not match the requested one.

Angular2 is expecting the `__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished` it passed in `callback` param in request.

But instead the `_todayMatchesCallback` is returned. You must either modify the middleware/backend to respect the `callback` param.

Comment: i call this URL http://localhost:4000/matches?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK, i must change the middleware for return callback instead _todayMatchesCallback ?

Comment: That's correct. You need to return callback passed as parameter instead of the _todayMatchesCallback. Also since you're new, if the answer is correct please remember to upvote it and accept :)